# Call method from controller in view (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanna call method from controller in view using the following code:

```
<%= memmory("#{broker.id}") %>
```

but its giving error "undefined method `memmory' for #<#:0xb3bf71e8>"

Comment: In which context that method is declared?

Comment: Could you give us more information (files) ? What is broker ? (inspect)

Comment: add in your controller(where method described)

`helper_method :memmory`

Comment: memmory is a function defined in a controller and "broker.id" is the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller add

`helper_method :memmory`

This will make your method available in views